# WSO2 API Manager Admin Services - Get List of Secondary Store Users

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, jaggery-js

I am using admin services to get a list of all users available in the store. I am calling the service through Jaggery using this code:

```
ws = require('ws');
var user = "";
var wsUser = new ws.WSRequest();

var optionsUser = new Object();
optionsUser.useSOAP = 1.2;
optionsUser.useWSA = 1.0;
optionsUser.action = "urn:listUsers";

wsUser.open(optionsUser, "https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService", false, "admin", "admin");

wsUser.send('<ser:listUsers xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org"><ser:filter></ser:filter><ser:maxItemLimit>-1</ser:maxItemLimit></ser:listUsers>');

resultUser = wsUser.responseText;
```

This gives me the list of users of the Primary Store. There is also a Secondary User Store connected to the APIM through Active Directory, and I would like to get the list of the users of that store as well.

Is there a way to get the list of users of all stores using admin service, if yes how would I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Do you see users from all userstores in "List Users" UI in carbon admin console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set '*' (i.e.asterisk) for search filter like below,  you should get users of all userstores.

```
  <ser:listUsers xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
     <ser:filter>*</ser:filter>
     <ser:maxItemLimit>-1</ser:maxItemLimit>
  </ser:listUsers>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It was so simple yet I spent a day and half working on it. I also found an alternative in jaggery using the user.Usemanager functions:

http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=UserManager